# HTML / Javascript - Trouble changing text when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some HTML code here:

```
<body>
<b style="font-size: 26px;">How the game works</b>
<u id="HowToPlay_HideShow" style="color: #9FF;">[hide]</u><br>
</body>
```

And I also used Javascript to turn the *hide* text into *show*, and *show* back into *hide* when clicked on.

```
<script>
var HowGameWorks_Hidden = false;
document.getElementById("HowToPlay_HideShow").onclick = function () {
    if (HowGameWorks_Hidden == false) {
        document.getElementById("HowToPlay_HideShow").innerHTML = "[show]";
        HowGameWorks_Hidden = true;
    }
    if (HowGameWorks_Hidden == true) {
        document.getElementById("HowToPlay_HideShow").innerHTML = "[hide]";
        HowGameWorks_Hidden = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

This, however, does not seem to work. Clicking on the *hide* and *show* text has no effect at all. So I tried removing this piece of code:

```
if(HowGameWorks_Hidden == true) {
    document.getElementById("HowToPlay_HideShow").innerHTML = "[hide]";
    HowGameWorks_Hidden = false;
  }
```

And it correctly turns the *hide* text into *show* when I click it (but, of course, does not turn the *show* text back into *hide*).

So how do I get my code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your second if statement will always get triggered if your first one does, since you set `HowGameWorks_Hidden` to `true` in it. You need to use an `else`:

```
if(HowGameWorks_Hidden == false) {
  document.getElementById("HowToPlay_HideShow").innerHTML = "[show]";
  HowGameWorks_Hidden = true;
}

else if(HowGameWorks_Hidden == true) {
  document.getElementById("HowToPlay_HideShow").innerHTML = "[hide]";
  HowGameWorks_Hidden = false;
}
```

Comment: But why? Why can't I simply use an If-statement instead of else? (Anyway it works now, thanks)

Comment: Read my edit, I added a bit of an explanation. Walk through what happens when `HowGameWorks_Hidden` is false - you hit your first if statement and as a result set `HowGameWorks_Hidden` to true. Now you hit your second if...and so you set `HowGameWorks_Hidden` to false. The else prevents you from going into the second if statement if the first succeeds.